# Laravel advance search

Tags: laravel

I have created a multiform search in laravel & it's not working properly

I have a table name `candidates` & there is a row named `salary` in which it has value like shown the the below image from `1 lac(s)` to `39 lac(s)`

[image: db]

The meaning it's not working properly is if i search `min salary = 0` & `max salary = 4` it's showing data between `0` to `4` but it's also showing data like `10` `18` `22`

controller code

```
    public function advance(Request $request)
    {
    $data = \DB::table('candidates');
    if( $request->name){
        $data = $data->where('name', 'LIKE', "%" . $request->name . "%");
    }
     if( $request->location){
        $data = $data->where('location', 'LIKE', "%" . $request->location . "%");
    }
     if( $request->key_skills){
        $data = $data->where('key_skills', 'LIKE', "%" . $request->key_skills . "%");
    }
    if( $request->gender){
        $data = $data->where('gender', 'LIKE', "%" . $request->gender . "%");
    }
     if( $request->pref_loc){
        $data = $data->where('pref_loc', 'LIKE', "%" . $request->pref_loc . "%");
    }
    if( $request->phoneno){
        $data = $data->where('phoneno', 'LIKE', "%" . $request->phoneno . "%");
    }
     if( $request->email){
        $data = $data->where('email', 'LIKE', "%" . $request->email . "%");
    }

    $min_ctc = $request->min_ctc;
    $max_ctc = $request->max_ctc;
    
    if ($min_ctc || $max_ctc) {
         $data = $data->where('salary', '>=', $min_ctc);
         $data = $data->where('salary','<=',$max_ctc);
     }
    
    $data = $data->paginate(10);
    $data2 = $data->total();
    return view('search', compact('data2'))->with('data',$data);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If `min salary = 0` translates to `salary > 0`, it's obvious that rows for any salary larger than 0 are returned. Have you checked the generated query to see whether the conditions are connected using `OR` or `AND`?

Comment: Also, if that column contains **text** (like: `5.50 Lac(s)`, you should run a text search. Is there any good reason not to store the salary as a number?

Comment: I don't think the you will get the required result as you have stored the `strings` rather than `integers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to search on string not on integer. In order to get the required result you have to type cast the string to integer or float and then perform the operation.

Here is the script that might help you.

```
    if ($min_ctc || $max_ctc) {
         $data = $data->whereRaw("CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(salary,' ', 1),UNSIGNED INTEGER) >= {$min_ctc}");
         $data = $data->whereRaw("CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(salary,' ', 1),UNSIGNED INTEGER) <= {$max_ctc}");
     }
```